# gcloud auth login with Docker does not work as it says in documentation

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, gcloud

I've followed the Docker instructions from here exactly: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#install-docker (click Alternative Methods to find Docker instructions).

But when I run:

```
docker run -t -i --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gcloud compute instances list
```

I get:

```
docker run -t -i --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gcloud compute instances list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account <account name>

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

It doesn't look like it's picking up that I already authenticated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The link doesn't point to anything about Docker, could you give correct link.

The encountered error output is pointing you to follow the two-step Google verification. If you provide :

```
gcloud auth login
```

command, the verification process will start, and then you will be able to manipulate your Google CLoud project

However this page [1] could guide you installing Docker on Google Cloud.

[1] - http://docs.docker.com/installation/google/

Comment: Click "Alternative Methods" to see Docker instructions. I've added this to my question.

Comment: the link is broken